# Regular expression using shorthand character class

Tags: javascript, regex

I have:

```
var regex = /[\w ]*/;

var str = 'My name is Robeet';

var match = str.match( regex );

document.write(match);
```

It returns :

```
My name is Robeet
```

Shouldn't this be an error since the "g" flag is not included for a global search?

I tried it with the "g" flag and got back the exact same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Shouldn't this be an error". What result were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern has a zero-or-more quantifier (`*`) so it will match any *sequence* of word characters or spaces. Since your whole string is meets that criteria, that's exactly what you should expect.

For comparison, try removing the quantifier:

```
'My name is Robeet'.match(/[\w ]/); 
// ["M"];
'My name is Robeet'.match(/[\w ]/g);
// ["M", "y", " ", "n", "a", "m", "e", ...]
```

Comment: And you obtain all the string instead of zero characters because a quantifier is greedy by default.

Answer (score 0):

from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)

> The g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)

And that's exactly what your regex is doing.

an absence of the **g** flag doesn't mean that your regex stops being greedy.  It will still try to find the **longest** possible pattern, It just won't find subsequent patterns, after your initial pattern.